# Detect elements removing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I need to capture event, when some element was removed from the DOM.

Removing can be done in following ways:

1. with `jQuery.remove()`
2. after hitting backspace in paragraph (that has "contentEditable" attr)

The only way, I know, to determine second case - is to count elements and compare after each hitting of <kbd>backspace</kbd> key.

Maybe there is a more elegant way exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are the [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent), specifically `DOMNodeRemoved` and `DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument`, but IE has historically not supported them. They are supposedly [supported in IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/26/dom-level-3-events-support-in-ie9.aspx).

Comment: note that `DOMNodeRemoved` fires before the node was actually removed